# How to compute projective coordinate Z in elliptic curve cryptography?

Tags: elliptic-curves, nist

I was working on affine coordinates and struggling with the computation time taken for operations and then I was advised to use projective coordinates so that mul-inverse operation can be avoided

Can somebody tell me how to compute 'z'?...I read at some places that z can be assumed as (1,1). If so then can it be used for implementing NistP256 curves?

Comment: https://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/nist-routines.pdf

Comment: Repeating myself: as an alternative to projective coordinates, you might want to have a look at the simpler technique of using affine coordinates, with all quantities kept as fractions, reducing numerator and denominator modulo $p$ when it gets much larger. Benefits that I expect: the math is easy; and you need to compute modular inverse only twice, when producing the final result; that removes the modular inverse performance bottleneck that you cite in a [related question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/31175/555).

Comment: @SEJPM          Yeah it is exactly the link which u suggested where i read about making z(1,1)(Routine 2.2.1). If I do so, then can I implement using the formula given [tag:here] (http://www.craigcostello.com.au/pairings/PairingsForBeginners.pdf) in section 2.4 where modular inversion is avoided ??

Comment: @fgrieu         For a curve like NISTP256 where the mod value is 256 bits long and I still end up with two 256-bit long inputs for modular inverse. I already tried that approach with affine coordinates but I'm not happy with the performance. Hence I seek an alternative for that and got the idea of using projective coordinates. If you still insist me to continue with affine coordinates, explain me why?

Comment: @abejoe: all methods I know for NISTP256 use some number of modular inverse operations with arguments of about 256 bits. The one that I propose uses very few, so that step will not become a bottleneck. And that method is readily understandable if one has already implemented and understood something with affine coordinates and modular inverse at each step. In light of your two [other](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/31175/555) related [questions](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/31173/555), you seem to be in that situation, and an easy understandable solution might be pedagogical.

Comment: @fgrieu         Can u share some example implementations of the method you are suggesting?....I dont have a very strong math background...So it will be very useful if it is in simple terms...Thanks a lot for your effort!